how to use column of a subquery into another subquery
I have a query, where i want to use the column connector from GRACREQPROV_GRP table  into another query of table GRFNMWRT_GRP for defining some case statements.
so basically i want the logic as IF connector has 'ASP' or 'P' then take rank=1
if connector starts with GRP then take rank 2,
but when i am trying to use connector column, it is giving error as column not found.
select distinct 
gruser.USERID as userid,
  gpv.CONNECTOR AS Server,
req.REQNO AS Ticket_no,
grfinst.CREATED_BY Ticket_created_by,
  zgrac.ZEMPNAME AS Ticket_created_by_NAME,
  grfn.CHANGED_BY Ticket_assigned_to,
  zgrac.ZEMPNAME AS Ticket_assigned_to_by_NAME,
  grfinst.INSTANCE_STATUS,
  grfinst.APPROVAL_STATUS,
  rnk

from 

`GRAC_GRP` req

LEFT JOIN 
(select distinct MANDT,REQ_ID,CONNECTOR from`GRACREQPROV_GRP`
 ) gpv
ON
  req.MANDT=gpv.MANDT
  AND req.REQ_ID=gpv.REQ_ID

left join 
(select distinct MANDT,EXTERNAL_KEY,FINISHED_AT,CREATED_BY,INSTANCE_ID,PROCESS_ID, INSTANCE_STATUS, APPROVAL_STATUS,EXTERNAL_KEY_DIS from `GRFNMWRT_GRP`
 
) grfinst 

on req.MANDT=grfinst.MANDT
AND req.REQNO=grfinst.EXTERNAL_KEY_DIS

LEFT JOIN 

(select distinct MANDT,ZEMPID,ZEMPNAME FROM `ZGRAC_EMP_GRP`) zgrac

on grfinst.MANDT=zgrac.MANDT
AND grfinst.CREATED_BY=zgrac.ZEMPID

LEFT JOIN 

(select distinct CHANGED_BY,INSTANCE_ID,LINEITEM_STATUS,TIMESTAMP_LONG,CONNECTOR
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY INSTANCE_ID, TIMESTAMP_LONG ASC) as rnk

 from `GRFNMWRT_GRP`  ) grfn

ON grfinst.INSTANCE_ID= grfn.INSTANCE_ID
AND grfn.CHANGED_BY= zgrac.ZEMPID

WHERE  
REQ.REQTYPE IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,124,125)
AND INSTANCE_STATUS IN("RUNNING","FINISHED")
AND LINEITEM_STATUS IN ("APPROVED", "REJECTED", "ONHOLD") 




I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

So you are certain that both tables "GRACREQPROV_GRP" and "GRFNMWRT_GRP" have that column? Did you try running both queries by themselves to make sure? You also mention that you are using case expressions, but I don't see any in your sample. Lastly, by having INSTANCE_STATUS and LINEITEM_STATUS in your where clause, you have basically made those two left joins as inner joins. Move them to the join logic.

no CONNECTOR is only present in GRACREQPROV_GRP table

Well there you go. You have answered your own question.

how ?? but  the query is not working

You are trying to select "connector" column from a table that doesn't have it (GRFNMWRT_GRP). If you want to use that column from another table then you need to join to it.

right, but to bring it because i want to perform some case operation in partitioning based on connector

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
